# Lunar Lander example stutters on my phone

Tags: java, android, performance

Hey I based my game off Google's Lunar Lander example. I have been getting considerable stuttering issues with my game even when I basically run a blank screen with a simple rectangle moving upwards.

I just grabbed the plain unmodified Lunar Lander example out of the SDK folder and ran it on my phone and noticed that I get noticable (albeit mild) stuttering on that too. It seems it isn't something I did to cause this. Does anyone else get stuttering with the basic Lunar Lander app? What could cause this? I have a Motorola Milestone.

Garbage collection is being called every 20 seconds or so while the stuttering is every 1-5 seconds so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

EDIT: if anyone would be willing to run a stripped performance-test version of my app on their phone to see if they get the same performance issues I will upload it somewhere.

Comment: What else do you have running on your phone?  Do you have some hungry apps running in the background?

Comment: I have tried turning my phone off, then on, and using taskiller to kill everything, but it still seems to be slow. Do you get stuttering with the Lunar Lander example? I am almost considering factory resetting my phone...

I don't get stuttering if I play angry birds on my phone.